# Asserting that a JDBC Response Contains a Request Property's Value

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, soapui

I have a JDBC Request test step in a SoapUI test case with a property `Foo` that has been assigned a value by a preceding Property Transfer test step - e.g. `12345`.

I would like to use a Contains assertion to check that the test step's response contains `Foo`'s value (since the test step's SQL Query is essentially a scalar `SELECT` - e.g. `SELECT TOP 1 FooColumn FROM SomeTable WHERE FooColumn = :Foo`), but this is proving a little tricky.

Working from [the SoapUI page on getting started with JDBC test steps](http://www.soapui.org/JDBC/getting-started.html), I tried `:Foo` in the Contains assertion: this yielded `-> Missing token [:Foo] in Response`.

So I tried `${:Foo}`: this "succeeded", but I found that `${:Whatever}` (`Whatever` not being a defined property) and `${}` "succeeded" too.  This does not seem correct.

How can I properly assert that the JDBC Request's response contains `Foo`'s value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that property expansion in a JDBC Request's assertions is like property expansion in a typical Test Request's (i.e. like [the SoapUI page on property expansions](http://www.soapui.org/Scripting-Properties/property-expansion.html) explains).

`:Foo` is particular to property expansion in the JDBC Request's *SQL Query*.  In the test step's Contains assertion, standard property expansion applies, and `${JDBC Request Name#Foo}` worked - succeeded rather than "succeeded".  In contrast, `${JDBC Request Name#Whatever}` failed as expected.

I am still unclear why `${:Foo}`, `${:Whatever}`, and `${}` all seemed to succeed.  If anyone can shed light on that part, I would love to understand.

**UPDATE:**

While the change to standard property expansion was correct, this change alone was still inadequate for the case that the Property Transfer test step preceding the JDBC Request test step transferred nothing to the property `Foo`.

In this case, the JDBC Request's Contains assertion produced a false positive because `Foo`'s value was as empty string, which the JDBC Request's (zero-rows but non-empty) response contained of course.  Changing the Contains assertion to `<FOOCOLUMN>${JDBC Request Name#Foo}</FOOCOLUMN>` fixed this problem.

This made me realize the likely reason that `${:Foo}`, `${:Whatever}`, and `${}` all seemed to succeed: they expanded to empty strings, which again the JDBC Request's response contained.  Consistent with this hypothesis, `<FOOCOLUMN>${:Foo}</FOOCOLUMN>` indeed failed with `-> Missing token [<FOOCOLUMN></FOOCOLUMN>] in Response` on reexamination.

Now I am simply left to wonder why `${:Foo}`, `${:Whatever}`, and `${}` expanded to empty strings where I would have expected them to produce errors.